# Add different custom markers for different post types in Google maps API

Tags: google-maps

I'm using the Google maps javascript API to create a map showing locations for multiple post types. I can create a custom map marker icon, but cannot figure out how to display a different marker icon for each of the different post types.

What I have so far is this:

```
var image = '<?php $the_post_type = get_post_type( get_the_ID() );
                    if ($the_post_type == 'surf-school') 
                        { echo home_url().'/wp-content/themes/blutek/images/surf-school-marker.png'; }
                    else if ($the_post_type == 'surfing-beach') 
                        { echo home_url().'/wp-content/themes/blutek/images/beach-marker.png'; }
                    ?>';
```

The above code displays the map with ALL of the posts having the same icon (beach-marker.png). Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

As requested, here is the full JS which creates the map:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = [
    <?php
    $post_query = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => 999, 'post_type' => array ('surfing-beach','surf-school')));
        if(!empty($post_query->posts)){

        foreach($post_query->posts as $post) { 
            $location_lat = get_post_meta($post->ID,'wp_gp_latitude',true);
            $location_long = get_post_meta($post->ID,'wp_gp_longitude',true);

        ?>
            ['<a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>', <?php echo $location_lat; ?>, <?php echo $location_long; ?>, 1],

        <?php } }?>
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('country-map-banner'), {
      zoom: 8,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.155145, -1.257973),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var image = '<?php $the_post_type = get_post_type( get_the_ID() );
                    if ($the_post_type == 'surf-school') 
                        { echo home_url().'/wp-content/themes/blutek/images/surf-school-marker.png'; }
                    else if ($the_post_type == 'surfing-beach') 
                        { echo home_url().'/wp-content/themes/blutek/images/beach-marker.png'; }
                    ?>';



    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        icon: image,
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }

    map.set('styles', [

    {"featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
            { "color": "#e5e3ef" },
            { "lightness": 15 }
        ]
    },
    {"featureType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {"saturation": 0},
            {"hue": "#e7ecf0"}
        ]
    },
    {"featureType": "road",
        "stylers": [
            {"visibility": "simplified"},
            {"saturation": -70}
        ]
    },
    {"featureType": "transit",
        "stylers": [
            {"visibility": "off"}
        ]
    },
    {"featureType": "poi",
        "stylers": [
            {"visibility": "off"}
        ]
    },
    {"featureType": "water",
        "stylers": [
            { "visibility": "simplified"},
            {"color": "#94d4fc"}
        ]
    },
    {"elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [
            { "visibility": "off" }
        ]
    },
    {"featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
            { "visibility": "off" }
        ]
    }

    ]);
  </script>
```

Comment: It is very hard to debug code when you don't have access to it (Why are you sure that your bug is there and not in some other part). Most likely you are not in the loop and therefor get_the_ID returns a constant value which depends on the last item which was accessed in the loop.

Comment: I also tried creating the loop within the var but the result was the same. Unfortunately I am working on the site locally on my machine so cannot share a link to the full code. I have a feeling this needs to be defined in the JavaScript but not sure.

Comment: without seeing more context a definitive answer is impossible.

Comment: I will add more tomorrow when I am back in the office. Thanks

Comment: Sorry about the delay in updating the question, work commitments got in the way. So I've added all the JS in which creates the map. Any help would be fantastic, thanks.